# Proof of two properties for a characteristic functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, characteristic-functions

**Definition** The indicator of $A\subset X$ is a function $\chi_A:X\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ defined as

$$
\chi_A(x):=\begin{cases}1\;\text{if}\;x\in A\\0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\end{cases}
$$

**Problem 1** Prove the following property for a characteristic function $\chi_A$ of a subset $A$ of a set $X$:

$$
|A|=\sum_{x\in X}\chi_A(x)
$$

**Problem 2** Check if the following equation holds:

$$
\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_A + \chi_B - \chi_A\chi_B
$$

---

<s>I don't know how to deal with the first problem yet because I have no idea how to apply the definition above. Any hints on how to start are welcome. I'll edit this entry once I know what needs to be done here.</s>

**Edit 1** First I'll add Brian M. Scott's proof for Problem 1:

$$
\begin{align}
|A|&=\sum_{x\in A}\underbrace{\chi_A(x)}_{1}\\
&=\sum_{x\in A}\chi_A(x)+\sum_{x\in X\setminus A}\underbrace{\chi_A(x)}_{0}\\
&=\sum_{x\in (A\cup (X\setminus A))}\chi_A(x)\\
&=\sum_{x\in X}\chi_A(x).
\end{align}
$$

because $A\cup(X\setminus A)=(A\cup X)\setminus(A\setminus A)=X\setminus \emptyset=X$.

---

Applying our introduced **Definition** on Problem 2 multiple times results to

$$
\begin{align}
\chi_{A\cup B}(x)&=\begin{cases}1\;\text{if}\;x\in A\cup B\\0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\cup B\end{cases}\\
&\overset{(*)}{=}\begin{cases}1\;\text{if}\;x\in A\lor x\in B\\0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\land x\notin B\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}1-0\;\text{if}\;x\in A\land x\notin B\\1-0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\land x\in B\\1-0\;\text{if}\;x\in A\land x\in B\\1-1\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\land x\notin B\end{cases}\\
&=1-\begin{cases}0\;\text{if}\;x\in A\land x\notin B\\0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\land x\in B\\0\;\text{if}\;x\in A\land x\in B\\1\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\land x\notin B\end{cases}\\
&=1-\left[\left(\begin{cases}1-0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\\1-1\;\text{if}\;x\in A\end{cases}\right)\left(\begin{cases}1-0\;\text{if}\;x\notin B\\1-1\;\text{if}\;x\in B\end{cases}\right)\right]\\
&=1-\left[\left(1-\begin{cases}0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\\1\;\text{if}\;x\in A\end{cases}\right)\left(1-\begin{cases}0\;\text{if}\;x\notin B\\1\;\text{if}\;x\in B\end{cases}\right)\right]\\
&=1-\big(1-\chi_A(x)\big)\big(1-\chi_B(x)\big)\\
&=\chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)-\chi_A(x)\chi_B(x).
\end{align}
$$

by using $(*)$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{A\cup B}&\Leftrightarrow \bigvee_{x\in X}\{x\notin (A\cup B)\}\\
&\overset{(*)}{\Leftrightarrow}\bigvee_{x\in X}\{x\notin A\land x\notin B\}\\
&\Leftrightarrow\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}.
\end{align}
$$

<s>I've got the feeling there's an easier way to solve the second problem. I'd be glad if anyone could give me hints for a shorter solution for this one as well.</s>

**Edit 2** I came up with a new proof for the second problem. Mind that

$$
\begin{align}
\chi_{\overline{\overline{A}}}(x)&=1-\chi_{\overline{A}}(x)\\
&=1-(1-\chi_A(x))\\
&=\chi_A(x).
\end{align}
$$

which gave me the idea for considering

$$
\begin{align}
\chi_{\overline{\overline{A\cup B}}}(x)&=1-\chi_{\overline{A\cup B}}(x)\\
&\overset{(*)}{=}1-\chi_{\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}}(x)\\
&\overset{(\times)}{=}1-\chi_{\overline{A}}(x)\chi_{\overline{B}}(x)\\
&=1-\big(1-\chi_A(x)\big)\big(1-\chi_B(x)\big)\\
&=\chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)-\chi_A(x)\chi_B(x).
\end{align}
$$

where I proved beforehand that $\chi_{A\cap B}(x)\overset{(\times)}{=}\chi_A(x)\chi_B(x)$ by applying the definition for characteristic functions multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question you have simply

$$|A|=\sum_{x\in A}1=\sum_{x\in A}1+\sum_{x\in X\setminus A}0=\sum_{x\in X}\chi_A(x)\;,$$

assuming, of course, that $A$ is a finite set.

HINT: For the second question just compare the two sides for each $x\in X$. Note that each $x\in X$ is in exactly one of the sets $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus A$, $A\cap B$, and $X\setminus(A\cup B)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now I've got an idea for the second problem. I'll try it tomorrow again.

Comment: @Stefan: You’re welcome. Feel free to leave a question if you get stuck.

Comment: I did the math though I end up doing it in a different way. Feedback is much appreciate.

Comment: @Stefan: Your approach is fine. Just a comment on the earlier result that you mention: you can prove that $\chi_{A\cap B}=\chi_A\chi_B$ simply by noting that $\chi_A\chi_B(x)=1$ iff $\chi_A(x)=\chi_B(x)=1$ iff $x\in A$ **and** $x\in B$ iff $x\in A\cap B$ iff $\chi_{A\cap B}(x)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll take this into account for future problems related to this topic.

Comment: @Stefan: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1 only holds for finite $A$. Since $x \not\in A \implies \chi_A(x) = 0$, the sum reduces to $\sum_{x \in X} \chi_A(x) = \sum_{x \in A} \chi_A(x) = \sum_{x \in A} 1 = |A|$.

Problem 2 is essentially the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). For $x \in X$, define the **point mass measure** of $x$ to be
$$ \mu_x(S) = \chi_S(x)
$$
Evidently $\mu$ is a measure. (Check this) By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle of measures,
$$ \mu_x(A \cup B) + \mu_x(A \cap B) = \mu_x(A) + \mu_x(B)
$$
which solves Problem 2.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating what a point mass measure is? I've never heard of it before and I didn't found a definition on Google, either.

Comment: @Stefan Also called a [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure)